# MVC 3 How to pass custom JS object to the controller?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing a collection of objects to MVC controller using $.post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727192/passing-a-collection-of-objects-to-mvc-controller-using-post)

I have that class:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public int BookID { get; set; }

    public List<SelectedBookFormat> SelectedFormats { get; set; }

    public SelectedBasketBook()
    {
        SelectedFormats = new List<SelectedBookFormat>();
    }
}

public class SelectedBookFormat
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

and an action:

```
public JsonResult Add(MyClass model)
{
...
}
```

I want to post that generated class from the client side:

(I generate that class object, then I use JSON.stringify() method)

```
model   {"BookID":"1","SelectedFormats":[{"ID":"4","Quantity":"34","Price":"44"},{"ID":"1","Quantity":"1","Price":"11"}]}
```

JS:

```
$.post('/Add', { 
                model : JSON.stringify({ BookID: '@Model.BookID', 
                                         SelectedFormats : formatsTab }) },
        function(res){}
                });
```

but the passed object is null on the server side, why ?

Answer (score 3):

```
var data = {};
data.BookId = 4;

var format = { };
format.ID = 3;
format.Quantity = 4;
format.Price = 2.2;

data.SelectedFormats = [];
data.SelectedFormats.push(format);

return $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'YourController/YourAction',
    dataType: 'json',
    traditional: true,
    data: {
        model: data
    }
});
```

For me the savior has been `traditional: true`.

Ps. In the server side there seems to be no need properties, so you could change them to fields and therefore write with lower-case letters. Then it would match writing style of the JS and still be valid in the server side. This is of course matter of taste.

Comment: Hmm the `BookID` is passed properly, but that list has the 0 item's count. If i Change in the `MyClass` from `List<SelectedBookFormat>` to `SelectedBookFormat[]` it's null